# Linq not be able to understand the alias in nested select

Tags: c#, linq

`FindAll()` is a function which gets table data as `IQueryable`.

Here when I run the query I got the following error LINQ expression

> 'x' error could not be translated either you need to rewrite query to that form or use the IEnumerable(), ToList() or ToListAsync()

I have this class

```
Public class ClassA
{
    Public int Name { get; set; }
    Public IEnumerable<ClassB> Result { get; set; }
}
```

I have a linq query in my service from which I need to get the required data

```
var response = from a in tbl1.FindAll()
               join b in tbl2.FindAll()
                    on a.ID equals b.requestID 
               into table3 
               from tablemap in table3.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new ClassA 
                          {
                              Name = a.Name,
                              Result = from x in table3
                                       select new ClassB
                                                  { 
                                                      // class B properties
                                                  }
                          };
```

Comment: What's the exact exception message? Also, show the entire query and classes in code that compiles. To much is unclear here.

Comment: Remove `from tablemap in table3.DefaultIfEmpty()`